# HTML to → WP Conversion

Tags: theme-development

I started to learn WP Theme development from a wordpress video tutorials on [Tutsplus](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/building-wordpress-themes-with-bootstrap).

It all went well and then I decided to practice a lot about HTML to WP theme Conversion.

I downloaded [this](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/) free bootstrap template.

I was able to create `header.php`, `footer.php`, nav menus and many functions that I learned from [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/building-wordpress-themes-with-bootstrap), but I got struck in `index.php` file creation and `content.php` file creation.

This is the HTML that is a little bit hurdle for me →

```
  <!-- Page Header -->
    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
    <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                        <span class="subheading">A Clean Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="post.html">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            Man must explore, and this is exploration at its greatest
                        </h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                            Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> on September 24, 2014</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="post.html">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            I believe every human has a finite number of heartbeats. I don't intend to waste any of mine.
                        </h2>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> on September 18, 2014</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="post.html">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            Science has not yet mastered prophecy
                        </h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                            We predict too much for the next year and yet far too little for the next ten.
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> on August 24, 2014</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <a href="post.html">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            Failure is not an option
                        </h2>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                            Many say exploration is part of our destiny, but it’s actually our duty to future generations.
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> on July 8, 2014</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <!-- Pager -->
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="next">
                        <a href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
```

Actually this part is bothering me a lot that whether it will go in `index.php` or `content.php` →

```
  <!-- Page Header -->
    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
    <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                        <span class="subheading">A Clean Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**My Difficulty →**
The front page is not showing Post Titles as was showing in the [HTML](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/), what is the mistake.
Here is my `index.php` and `content.php` files →

***INDEX.PHP →***

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package html2wpsecond
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <!-- Page Header -->
    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
    <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                        <span class="subheading">A Clean Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>


    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <?php If ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php else: ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('content','none' ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>



                <!-- Pager -->
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="next">
                        <a href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

**CONTENT.PHP →**

```
<?php  

/*
# =======================================
# content.php
#
# The Theme
# =======================================
*/  

?>

<div id=post-<?php the_ID(); ?> <?php post_class('post col-md-6'); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink( ); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="post-thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
            </a>


    <div class="post-preview">
        <header>
            <?php
                echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"><h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3></a>';
                blogeto_post_meta();
            ?>
        </header>
            <?php the_content(__('Read More', 'blogeto')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "Main Content" block in index.php with the following. This way you do not need a content.php file and can query the posts right in index.php. The Next/Previous post navigation will be functional as-well.

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

                <?php
                // Start the loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    ?>
                    <div class="post-preview">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h2 class="post-title">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </h2>
                            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </h3>
                        </a>
                        <p class="post-meta">Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> on <?php the_time('jS F Y') ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php

                // End of the loop.
                endwhile;
                ?>


            <!-- Pager -->
            <ul class="pager">
                <li class="next">
                    <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
                    <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```